# How to define caption width in longtable?

Tags: captions, longtable, width

I have a `longtable` within a `landscape` environment. Not sure the landscape is relevant but ...

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{lll}
 \caption{bla bla bla long ...}
 table & table & table
\end{longtable}
\begin{landscape}
```

I would like to change the width of the caption that is too narrow for my taste.

I tried with the caption package that is supposed to work within the table environment

```
\captionsetup{width=5cm}
```

I also tried to put my caption in a parbox

```
\parbox{5cm}{\caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...}}
```

As proposed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322563/make-latex-table-caption-same-width-as-table

But it does not change anything or throws out an error.

Would you have an idea?

Comment: I don't know what you're doing but a) your example above does not work at all and b) if I use a small document it works ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is most likely due to a wrongly place `\captionsetup`.

I doubt the usefulness of `landscape` and `longtable` but here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{caption}


\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\captionsetup{width=5cm}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{lll}
 \caption{\blindtext} 
\endfirsthead
 table & table & table \tabularnewline
 table & table & table \tabularnewline 
 table & table & table \tabularnewline
 table & table & table \tabularnewline
 table & table & table \tabularnewline 
 table & table & table \tabularnewline
 table & table & table \tabularnewline
 table & table & table \tabularnewline 
 table & table & table \tabularnewline
 table & table & table \tabularnewline
 table & table & table \tabularnewline 
 table & table & table \tabularnewline
 table & table & table \tabularnewline
 table & table & table \tabularnewline 
 table & table & table \tabularnewline
 table & table & table \tabularnewline
 table & table & table \tabularnewline 
 table & table & table \tabularnewline
 table & table & table \tabularnewline
 table & table & table \tabularnewline 
 table & table & table \tabularnewline
 table & table & table \tabularnewline
 table & table & table \tabularnewline 
 table & table & table \tabularnewline
 table & table & table \tabularnewline
 table & table & table \tabularnewline 
 table & table & table \tabularnewline
 table & table & table \tabularnewline
 table & table & table \tabularnewline 
 table & table & table \tabularnewline
 table & table & table \tabularnewline
 table & table & table \tabularnewline 
 table & table & table \tabularnewline
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hum I feel rather stupid right now. Actually, I used \captionsetup within the table and not outside of it! And yes, sorry for the example given a little too quickly. No need for \tabularnewline though. 
So thanks, it's working now :-)

Comment: @tuculuxu The `\captionsetup` should work inside the `longtable`. If not, this is a bug and should be reported... I just tried it out using the test document above; placing `\captionsetup{...}` right before `\caption` inside the `longtable` works fine here. If you have a document where it does not, please report.

Answer (score 7):

As indicated in the documents of longtable package. You can

> Set the width of the caption with a command such as `\setlength{\LTcapwidth}{2in}` in the preamble of your document.

For example, to fit the caption length to table width (equals to textwidth), you can do

```
\setlength{\LTcapwidth}{\textwidth}
```

Then it should be work.